# 1120: Access of undefined property "selectObject"

Tags: object, actionscript-3, colors, actionscript

hi I'm a complete newbie when it comes to coding and as I followed a tutorial on YouTube on how to create a coloring game and followed the instructions to a tee I tried renaming my instance name of the symbol but I still get the errors

}

```
    private function addEvents(...objects){
        for(var i:Number=0; i<objects.length; i++){
            objects[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, selectObject);
        }
    }
    
    private function selectedObject(e:MouseEvent):void{
        myObject = e.target;
        ColorPickerMc.spectrum.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateColor);
        
    }
    private function backtoMainScreen(e:MouseEvent) {
        MovieClip(stage.getChildAt(0)).gotoAndStop("Intro");
    }
    
    private function updateColor(e:MouseEvent){
        hexaColor = "0x"+bitmapDt.getPixel(ColorPickerMc.spectrum.mouseX, ColorPickerMc.spectrum.mouseY).toString(16);
        
        ct.color = hexaColor;
        myObject.transform.colorTransform = ct;
    }
    
    private function freezeColor(e:MouseEvent){
        myObject.transform.colorTransform = ct;
        ColorPickerMc.spectrum.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, updateColor);
    }
```

the problems are on line 29, line 34, line 46, and line 50

and the Youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sxig7-ZVdLw from 37:00 to 39:00 I should have the desired results just by following the instructions, but I got these errors how do i fix these?

Comment: The method name is **selectedObject** but you try to subscribe some other method **selectObject** (read these two over until you finally spot the difference).

Comment: Damn, thank you for pointing this out, now I feel like an idiot not noticing it sooner